# Three.js pivot rotation is wrong when using sprites

Tags: three.js

I have a parent container called 'cubeAndLabelContainer' and a cube and a label (sprite) inside it.

The problem is that the location for pivot of the label is different than the cube's, even though the mesh and the sprite are both part of the 'cubeAndLabelContainer':

```
var cubeAndLabelContainer;

function initObjects()
{
    cubeAndLabelContainer = new THREE.Object3D();

    var cube  = _createCube();
    var label = _createLabel();

    cube.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
    label.position.set(0, 20, 0 );
    cubeAndLabelContainer.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );

    cubeAndLabelContainer.add( cube );
    cubeAndLabelContainer.add( label );

    scene.add( cubeAndLabelContainer );
}
```

The label should rotate around the cube, but instead they appear like two separate objects rotating at the same rate.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRpgPp

If I add more meshes to the 'cubeAndLabelContainer', their rotation and location is perfectly fine and aligned correctly relative to each other. But when I do the same with sprites, the pivot is different for some reason..

Any suggestions please?

Comment: I made the same mistake when I started using sprites. The canvas is much larger than you think. I modified the code pen so you can see your code is working fine. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpVNrw  You just need to center the text, and/or set the size of your canvas so it doesn't default of 300x150. As well, it's not good to send a texture to Three.js that has sides that aren't a power of two. Always be mindful of the pixel size of canvases when using three.js.

Comment: Also, you have to align the text on the canvas yourself [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/0LtjLwdx/)

Comment: @Radio thank you very much!! Please post your comment as an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: @prisoner849 Thanks for the hint! )